# Installing HomeBrew doesn't work on Mojave

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I type in Terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and I get back

```
illegal variable name
```

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is the same issue? https://discourse.brew.sh/t/illegal-variable-name-error-mac-high-sierra/3361/2.

```
could you run bash before pasting /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" there?
```

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to include the information from the link? That way, the information will be provided here even when the linked to article vanishes in the future.

Comment: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md - "A Bourne-compatible shell for installation (e.g. bash or zsh) - 
The one-liner installation method found on brew.sh requires a Bourne-compatible shell (e.g. bash or zsh). Notably, fish, tcsh and csh will not work."

Answer (score 1):

Simply open the terminal. Write the command as

```
bash
```

and press Enter button. Paste the same command as -

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```